# Colouring lines in table when using multicolumn

Tags: tables, color

I was wondering if it is possible to colour specific lines in a table, especially when using multicolumn. I'm using [www.tablesgenerator.com](http://www.tablesgenerator.com) to create my table, as they are getting a bit bigger. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-7}
                                                        & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}Something}                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{275D90} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}Something} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}}                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}1}         & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} &                          &                          &                          &                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}2}         &                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} &                          &                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}3}         &                          &                          &                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to modify the code so that the lines for the white, black and grey cells, are grey. But the lines bordering the blue cells, or the line on the right, should be black. I tried it with `\arrayrulecolor{gray}` before the multicolumn, but that influences the colour bordering the blue cells too. Is there any easy solution for that problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Would you please update your code to be a minimal working example folks can run through TeX?  Often your choice of packages affects the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw, sorry, I thought I added it, but I seem to have forgotten it. It's edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution using `hhline` and defining a new column type to replace the `|` separators  between column, heavily inspired by the `boldline` package (from the `shipunov` bundle). I'm not too sure if some vertical lines also had to be gray, but this can be changed. In addition, I loaded the `caption` package, to have a better vertical spacing between caption and table. As the request is soùewhat ambiguous, I give two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hhline}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{W}{!{\color{Snow3}\vrule\@width\arrayrulewidth}} %[1]#1
\makeatother
\newcommand\normalcell[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
 \centering \caption{My caption} \label{my-label}
 \begin{tabular}{l|*{5}{lW}l! {\vline}}%
 \hhline{~|------}
 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}Something} \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor[HTML]{275D90} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}Something} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}} \\
 \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}----}
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}1} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \normalcell{} & \normalcell{} & \normalcell{} & \\
 \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}--}
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}2} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \normalcell{} & \\
 \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}----->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}


\begin{table}[]
  \centering \caption{My caption} \label{my-label}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}
  \begin{tabular}{l|*{5}{lW}l|}%
    \hhline{~|------}
    & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}Something} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{275D90} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}Something} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}1} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & & & &\normalcell{} \\
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{Snow3}}------>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}2} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & & \\
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{Snow3}}------>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}3} & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems similar to AboAmmar answer. But how did you achieve the squares to look more regular?

Comment: It's probably a visual effect: I managed to have black lines between two white cells, with the `\cellnormal` macro. The difficulty with your requirements comes from the fact that using `\arrayrulecolor`, all subsequent lines (horizontal *and* vertical) change colour. This is a problem for vertical rules, which I circumvented using the `W` column type (which replaces the `|` separator). What I'm not sure of is whether all gray lines are where you want them to be.

Comment: Ah, I thought some of the commands have that effect. \arrayrulecolor is not really a requirement, it's just something I tried, which not worked, exactly for the reason you mentioned. For the style, have a look at AboAmmars answer. That is the style I want. I think my explanation was not too clear on that. ;)

Comment: If I understand well, all lines between small squares should be grey?

Comment: Exactly. The rest should be black. The grey ones should be a bit less prominent, but they should be there to make the distinction still.

Comment: OK, that' s simpler finally. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Patrick: I've updated my answer,  adding a code for colouring lines  more like you want.

Comment: Quick question. When I put multiple columns beside each other. Is it possible to avoid the grey going through the vertical black line?

Comment: Do you mean the vertical black line on the right side of the table? That is normally done with the final `|` in `\hhline{------|}`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out too at the end. I was just a bit confused. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-7}
                                                        & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}Something}                                                                                                          \\\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{275D90}

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}Something} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}}                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}1}         & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} &                          &                          &                          &                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}2}         &                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} &                          &                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}3}         &                          &                          &                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\arrayrulecolor{<colour>}` at appropriate places.

Comment: This seems an easier solution, but the design is not as I need it. AboAmmar answer provides the correct design, although in a complicated way. I couldn't achieve that with \arrayrulecolor{<colour>}, do you think it's possible? It would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. Then, the key `hvlines` will draw all the rules excepted in the blocks and in the corners specified by the key `corners` (the corners are computed automatically from the empty cells).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north west
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{black}{3-2,3-3,4-4,4-5,5-5,5-6}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{4-3,5-4}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{6195C9}{1}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}{3-1,4-1,5-1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{275D90}{2}
\Body
  & \Block{1-*}{Something} \\
  Something & \Block{1-*}{} \\
  1 & \Block{*-*}{} & & & & \\
  2 & \\
  3 & \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

The package `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's now possible to use those nodes with Tikz to draw the gray rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{black}{3-2,3-3,4-4,4-5,5-5,5-6}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{4-3,5-4}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{6195C9}{1}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}{3-1,4-1,5-1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{275D90}{2}
\Body
  & \Block{1-*}{Something} \\
  Something & \Block{1-*}{} \\
  1 & \Block{*-*}{} & & & & \\
  2 & \\
  3 & \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [gray!20,line width = 0.5pt]
    \foreach \i in {4,5} { \draw (\i-|2) -- (\i-|7) ; } 
    \foreach \j in {3,4,5,6} { \draw (3-|\j) -- (6-|\j) ; }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

The output is not perfect because the gray rules have been drawn after the black ones. It's possible to draw another black rectangle in order to have a perfect output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{black}{3-2,3-3,4-4,4-5,5-5,5-6}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{4-3,5-4}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{6195C9}{1}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}{3-1,4-1,5-1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{275D90}{2}
\Body
  & \Block{1-*}{Something} \\
  Something & \Block{1-*}{} \\
  1 & \Block{*-*}{} & & & & \\
  2 & \\
  3 & \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [gray!20,line width = 0.5pt]
    \foreach \i in {4,5} { \draw (\i-|2) -- (\i-|7) ; } 
    \foreach \j in {3,4,5,6} { \draw (3-|\j) -- (6-|\j) ; }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \tikz \draw (3-|2) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

**You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes.**

[image: Output of the third code]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}    
\begin{document}

%\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} % No need for this in your final version
\newcommand{\VLINE}{\multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{gray}\vline}}}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hhline{~|------}
                                                        & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}Something}                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{275D90} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}Something} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{275D90}}                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}1}         & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{gray}\vline}}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} &\VLINE{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \VLINE{} &\VLINE{}&\VLINE{}&\\ 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}------}%\hline
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}2}  &\VLINE{}&\VLINE{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}&\VLINE{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}}&\VLINE{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}}&\VLINE{}&                          \\ 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}------}%\hline
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{6195C9}3}&\VLINE{}&\VLINE{}&\VLINE{}&\VLINE{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}&\VLINE{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}}& \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Well, this is way too complicated, but with `hhline` package, one can define custom rules for individual cells. For gray vertical rules, we can define

```
\newcommand{\VLINE}{\multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{gray}\vline}}}
```

and for horizontal segments, we can set different segment colors by:

```
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}------}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
```

where the number of dashes represent the number of cells and to restore the black rules we add `\arrayrulecolor{black}` at the end.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about. Although, the lines seem pretty thick. Is that normal? But yes, it seems complicated indeed...

Comment: @Patrick Right, the lines are too thick because I added `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}` just to make the lines clearer. Sure you can remove that line.

Comment: Do you think this can be solved simpler? Otherwise, I think I'll go with this solution. Although it will be a bit messy with a bigger table...